ogr2ogr select no longer works
I use to be able to select arbitrary attribute data. For example:
SELECT '123' AS 'ID' FROM layername
This now results in the error message:
ogr2ogr failed: ERROR 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected string, expecting identifier. Occurred around :
SELECT '123' AS 'ID' FROM layername
^
I optionally select other attributes as well that are in the shapefile. It seems now ogr2ogr now only allows attributes that exist in the shapefile. The error message itself is bogus (misleading) I believe.
This is on Debian 12.
ogr2ogr --version
GDAL 3.6.2, released 2023/01/02
Please advise.

Identifiers should not be single-quoted but either left alone or be double-quoted (doc)
SELECT '123' AS ID FROM layername


Thanks. Tested and resolved. I will point out that this is a change from an earlier release. My code has worked as shown for quite a long time before the update.
